# How do I auto-layout boxes on a flowchart?

Tags: graph, flowchart, graph-algorithm

I have some data that represents a flowchart. (A bunch of Jira statuses and their transitions to other statuses.)

I also have [a crude way to position each flowchart item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961734/how-do-i-generate-an-openoffice-draw-document) on an A4 page in an OpenOffice Draw document. (Though better suggestions welcome for that.)

However, I'd prefer not to have to output a line of boxes and re-arrange them by hand, especially since I might need to re-generate the flowchart several times.

This seems like a common problem, so there must be existing algorithms/techniques that can analyse several items (and the links between them) and do a decent job of placing them in good positions.

Any suggestions on how best to do this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518685/

Comment: Thanks for that link - looking at [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) and I have a working digraph from my data, so that transfers my problem back into producing a (vector) format that OpenOffice Draw can import.